# Magento2: Wrong path of static contents

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend, static-content

I know so many others have asked the same question but still no reliable ans is available.

Suddenly my site is hitting the wrong path of static content (CSS/JS/IMAGES) because of this my site is not loading.

static path is adding version140*****

Same problem discussed in [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158523/magento-2-1-3-static-content-issue)

But still same problem is there for my custom CSS still url is wrong.

> pub/static/**version1487328792**/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Codilar_RenderBook/css/style.css.

Version part is getting added automatically.

Comment: I have the same problem with this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to Magento "Signing" the files. Essentially it forces Magento to regenerate the public static files on page reload by adding the current timestamp to the files.

This may have changed due to an upgrade of version so check the following configuration is set to no:

```
Store -> Configuration -> Developer -> Static Files Settings -> Sign Static Files
```

Be sure to flush the caches after this has been changed

Answer (score 4):

I tried EVERYTHING to no avail, so I finally decided to do it the "wrong" way:

```
<Magento-base-URL>/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Url/Signature.php
```

Commented out line 66

```
$baseUrl .= $this->renderUrlSignature() . '/';
```

After that the admin loaded fine and I checked the "signage" setting. It was still set to "YES" although I had set it to "0" in the database - maybe wrong scope or whatever.

Then I uncommented line 66 back in and it still works fine.

4 hours of my life gone, hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: You saved me about 4 hours of my life.

Comment: it does helps me :)

Answer (score 4):

The issue lies with the way magento checks if the the theme is allowed. It uses a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR on windows this is a backslash: \ the array with theme_names in the function isThemeAllowed() is formated with forward slashes. So the checks fails, and return a 404 error.
replace the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR with a forward-slash and your files will load dynamic.

File: magento-root\vendor\magento\framework\App\StaticResource.php

Line: 171

Change

```
`if (!($this->isThemeAllowed($params['area'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .` $params['theme'])
```

To

```
`if (!($this->isThemeAllowed($params['area'] . "/" . $params['theme'])`
```

Comment: You saved me so much time with this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the `pub/static/.htaccess` file in developer mode you don't need to run any compilation command: Magento will create symlinks to files as soon as they are requested. That means that changes to static assets will be visible immediately, provided you also have cache disabled.

You can delete the `pub/static/frontend` or `pub/static/adminhtml` instead.

In default mode assets are materialized in pub/static subfolder, meaning they are created (copied, not symlinked) at first request. If you modify them you have to flush the cache to have them updated.

In production mode assets are not materialized (causing 404 HTTP error upon request) until you run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.

Comment: what about the version14****** which is getting added in static content url

Comment: just delete .htaccess file remove then check .htaccess generate or not if not then issue remian..

Comment: removed `pub/static/.htaccess` issue remains same (.htaccess is not generating) after I put .htaccess manually all css/js is loading properly except my modules css/js (version14******** getting added in it).

Comment: More detail please Refer this article..http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder

Answer (score -2):

I did update on magento´s database and its works for me.

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://localhost/magento2' WHERE `core_config_data`.`config_id` = 2;

UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'https://localhost/magento2' WHERE `core_config_data`.`config_id` = 3;