# Magento 2 pub/static content will result to 404

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I'm having a problem in deploying my magento 2 site. It's weird because after content deploy the site will reload slowly and it's not generating the proper static content path. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Attached is the screenshot of the console log of the site.

[image]

Comment: Please check if your pub/static contains .htaacess file or not?

Comment: Hi Rakesh long time no see. Ok I'll check thanks I will update you if there is none

Comment: It has .htaccess file

Comment: Have you run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command ?

Comment: Yes I did all the required commands like that. I created a room Rakesh can you join and we will discuss there?

Comment: I noticed something different in the static files path this one /pub/static/version1493272677/frontend/SCI/luma/en_US/Magento_Theme/css/homepage_headers.css"" why it contains version123213423 folder? I think it's the reason why the site is not showing up properly

Comment: I fixed my own problem. Thanks to this thread: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160474/magento2-wrong-path-of-static-contents